# If statement for date range

Tags: php, mysql, date, if-statement

I have date join and would only like to compare the day & month. As shown below if an employee joined between 1st January until 30th June, it would output Jan-June.

However, my problem now is that if the date join is between July until December, it would still output as Jan - June. Is there any problem with my code? Thanks.

If I `echo $date_join` the **output would be 15/08**

```
$date_join =(date("d/m", strtotime($row['date']))); 
if (($date_join >= '01/01') && ($date_join <= '30/06'))
{
    echo 'Jan - June';
}
else if (($date_join >= '01/07') && ($date_join <= '31/12'))
{
    echo 'July - Dec';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$date_join_month =date("n", strtotime($row['date']));
$date_join_month=inval($date_join_month);
if ($date_join_month >= 1 && $date_join_month <= 6)
{
    echo 'Jan - June';
}
else if ($date_join_month >= 7 && $date_join_month <= 12)
{
    echo 'July - Dec';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a date object with a string, this won't work. You need to change the string to a date too. For example:

```
$january = (date("d/m", strtotime('01/01')));
$june = (date("d/m", strtotime('30/06')));

if (($date_join >= $january) && ($date_join <= $june))
{
    echo 'Jan - June';
}
```